# Why does apache return a 404 response for a file that exists?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-perl

I have an apache server whose main purpose is to handle RPC requests.  All such requests hit a url that begins with a fixed prefix (e.g., `/rpc`)  I use a `Location` directive to set the handler for this URL (e.g., `<Location /rpc>...</Location>`).

I'd now like this server to also serve static files.  I put an `index.html` file into its `DocumentRoot` but cannot get apache to serve it to me.  Instead, I get 404 responses.  The access log shows this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2010:11:41:52 -0400] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 208
```

The error log shows this:

```
[...] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /www/htdocs/index.html
```

This error message is a filthy lie.  I can copy and paste that path and run `ls /www/htdocs/index.html` and see that the file does indeed exist.

Things I have tried so far:

- Checked all permissions in full path to the file: all dirs are 755, all files are 644
- Checked ownership: all dirs and files are owned by the same user that apache is running as
- Set `LogLevel debug` (no new messages appeared in the logs)
- Added a `<Location />` block with a `SetHandler default-handler` directive
- Added a `<Location /index.html>` block with a `SetHandler default-handler` directive
- Moved both of these `Location` blocks above and below the `<Location /rpc>` block
- Ran `dtruss` and did not see apache issue a single `stat()` call while processing the request

I'm running out of ideas.  What else should I try?

(I'm using apache 2.2.12 on Mac OS X 10.5.8 and apache 2.2.3 on CentOS 5.4.)

Comment: I think this question turned out to be more appropriate for StackOverflow.com.  If anyone powerful enough to move/migrate this question over to there agrees with me, please do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turned out to hinge on a piece of information not present in my question—but the `dtruss` output should have been a big hint!

I have a `PerlMapToStorageHandler Apache2::Const::OK` directive in my apache configuration as per [the suggestion in the mod_perl documentation](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/http.html#PerlMapToStorageHandler).  This is a host-wide setting and it prevents apache from calling `ap_directory_walk()` and `stat()`ing a bunch of files every time it gets a request.  This is desirable when all of your URIs are "virtual" (i.e., don't correspond to real files on disk) but it also means that you can't serve any static files!

My solution was to create a custom `PerlMapToStorageHandler` routine that avoids the `stat()` calls for every file except the one I want to serve:

```
package MyMapToStorageHandler;

use strict;  
use Apache2::RequestRec();
use Apache2::Const -compile => qw(DECLINED OK M_TRACE);

sub handler {
    my $r = shift;

    # Fall through to the default handling for TRACE requests and requests
    # for the index.html file.
    if ($r->method_number == Apache2::Const::M_TRACE || $r->uri eq '/index.html') {
        return Apache2::Const::DECLINED;
    }

    # Skip ap_directory_walk stat() calls by just returning OK
    return Apache2::Const::OK;
}

1;
```

Then, in my `httpd.conf` file I replaced my existing `PerlMapToStorageHandler Apache2::Const::OK` directive with this:

```
PerlLoadModule MyMapToStorageHandler
...
PerlMapToStorageHandler MyMapToStorageHandler
```

That did the trick.